# mount error = 5 when mounting ceph cluster

Tags: juju, ceph

Im using MAAS and juju to configure a small 3 node test cluster.

I have followed the Ceph charm read me instruction.  Now I want to mount the ceph cluster.

I've created a secret file from the `/etc/ceph/*keyring` on the ceph clients.
When I try the mount, it takes several minutes and comes back with `mount error = 5`

```
$ mount.ceph nkant.ceph:/ /mnt -o name=admin,secretfile=root.secret
    mount error = 5 Input/output error
```

A google search on this tells me the issue is due the no MDS process responding.
I've taken a look on the ceph nodes and there does not appear to be any trace of an MDS process.

> ***Should MDS have been installed as part of deploying the ceph charm or am I missing a step somewhere ?***
>
> ***Could this be an issue here ?***

My ceph health is `HEALTH_WARN:`

```
$ ceph -s

   health HEALTH_WARN 6 pgs degraded; 6 pgs stuck unclean
   monmap e2: 3 mons at {a8nke=192.168.2.21:6789/0,f7fby=192.168.2.22:6789/0,nkant=192.168.2.23:6789/0}, election epoch 6, quorum 0,1,2 a8nke,f7fby,nkant
   osdmap e7: 3 osds: 3 up, 3 in
   pgmap v112: 192 pgs: 186 active+clean, 6 active+degraded; 0 bytes data, 3103 MB used, 21439 MB / 24542 MB avail
   mdsmap e1: 0/0/1 up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ceph charm currently only supports Ceph Object and Block storage services; hence you won't find any running MDS daemons and support for CephFS right now!